# mlocate has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, 20.04, locate

I just upgraded to ubuntu 20.4. Trying to install locate resulted as follows :

```
sudo apt install mlocate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mlocate is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mlocate' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: It's there though you didn't provide architecture, so refer @ArchismanPanigrahi's comment (`mlocate | 0.26-3ubuntu3   | focal   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. "sudo apt update" solved the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 3):

Before installing a package in Ubuntu it is advisable to get an updated list of packages from the Internet by running the command `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`.

So you should proceed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mlocate
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mlocate
```

Hopefully, your issue should be handled.